# Data Access Tool failed to connect db2

Tags: db2, windows

I have a DB2 installed on windows 2012

Server name: test017330VM

OS: Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter

DB2 port:50000

DB2 Version:DB2 v11.1.1010.160

Database:dbtest.  (this is created by command 'DB2 Create database dbtest')

Local user:db2admin. (DB2 was installed under this account and it has the admin privilege on both windows and db2).

Password:Aa1!Aa1!;

I tried to run  Data Access Tool (v4) on the same server, but got the error immediate after I click the connect:

> Could not connect to data source 'New Data Source':
>   An internal network library error has occurred. A network level syntax error has occurred.

Here is the connection string:

> Provider=DB2OLEDB;User ID=db2admin;Password=Aa1!Aa1!;Initial Catalog=dbtest;Network Transport Library=TCPIP;Host CCSID=37;PC Code Page=1252;Network Address=test017330VM;Network Port=50000;Package Collection=**MSPKG**;Process Binary as Character=False;Units of Work=RUW;DBMS Platform=**DB2/NT**;Use Early Metadata=False;Defer Prepare=False;DateTime As Char=False;Rowset Cache Size=0;Datetime As Date=False;AutoCommit=True;Authentication=Server;Decimal As Numeric=False;Derive Parameters=False;LoadBalancing=False;Persist Security Info=True;Cache Authentication=False;Connection Pooling=False;

Please shed some light on it.

1. why it's a syntax error?
2. What is MSPKG  in the parameter Package Collection=**MSPKG**?
3. what is 'DB2/NT' correct?

Comment: What's "Data Access Tool (v4)"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

resolved by upgrading the Data Access Tool (v4) to Data Access Tool (v5)